# Android Java Vertical scroll view size

Tags: java, android, size, scrollview, screen

I have a very simple activity with a vertical scroll view (`mainscreen.xml` below).

This vertical scroll view has a linear layout child view.

I dynamically add text views as children to this linear layout (`populateLinlayWithTextViews()` below).

Later, after these text view children have been added, I can scroll the vertical scroll view (`onScrollChange()` below).

And I can measure the visible part of the vertical scroll view (`getHeight()`).

**My problem is that I need to know earlier than at scroll time what is the maximum height of the visible part of the vertical scroll view.**

mainscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    int n_statusBarHeight = resources.getIdentifier( "status_bar_height", "dimen", "android"); // 36px

    populateLinlayWithTextViews();

    // HERE
    ScrollView sv = sv = findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    int n_svVisiblePartHeight = sv.getHeight(); // 0px

    View.OnScrollChangeListener onScrollChangedListener
    = new View.OnScrollChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
        {
            ScrollView sv = sv = findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
            int n_svVisiblePartHeight = sv.getHeight(); // 680px
        }
    }

    sv = findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    sv.setOnScrollChangeListener(onScrollChangedListener);
}

public void populateLinlayWithTextViews()
{
    LinearLayout linlay = findViewById(R.id.linlay);
    int n_viewHeight = 81; // px

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            n_viewHeight);

    for(int n_i=0 ; n_i<20 ; n_i++)
    {
        TextView tvNew = new TextView(m_app);
        tvNew.setText(n_i + " - test");
        tvNew.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)); // black
        tvNew.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 40);
        tvNew.setLayoutParams(params);

        linlay.addView(tvNew, linlay.getChildCount());
    }
}
```

When I scroll the vertical scroll view, I can see that `n_svVisiblePartHeight`'s value is `680px`.

But I need to know this value earlier `// HERE`.

But `// HERE`, the value I get is `0px`.

Can you help me?

**EDIT 1**

I need to know this height because:

- example 1: I would like to know initially the index of the text view that will be at the bottom of the (visible) screen after I have populated
  the linear layout with text views ;
- example 2: given this height `X` I'm looking for, let's say that I would like `10` text views to be visible initially, I would like to determine `X/10` which will be the height of the text views, so that I can put it dynamically in `n_viewHeight`.

**EDIT 2**

I just need to know the height of the red arrow below, a soon as I can in the lifecycle of the activity and preferably before I add text views to the linear layout or right after (`// HERE`):

[image: Height I'm looking for.]

**EDIT 3**

I don't know if theoretically that's true:

```
n_scrollViewVisibleHeightInPx =
    n_displayHeightInPx
  - n_actionBarHeight
  - n_navigationBarHeightInPx
  + n_statusBarHeightInPx;
```

... but practically `n_scrollViewVisibleHeightInPx` is the height of the space designated by the red arrow in the image above.

To get these various heights, below are the methods I used:

```
private int returnStatusBarHeightInPx()
{
int       n_statusBarHeightInPx = -1;
Resources resources             = null;
int       n_idStatusBarHeight   = -1;

    resources = getResources();

    n_idStatusBarHeight = resources.getIdentifier( "status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if(n_idStatusBarHeight > 0)
    {
        n_statusBarHeightInPx = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(n_idStatusBarHeight);
    }
    else
    {
        n_statusBarHeightInPx = 0;
    }
    return n_statusBarHeightInPx;
}

private int returnNavigationBarHeightInPx()
{
int       n_navigationBarHeightInPx = -1;
Resources resources                 = null;
int       n_idNavigationBarHeight   = -1;

    resources = getResources();
    n_idNavigationBarHeight = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");

    if(n_idNavigationBarHeight > 0)
    {
        n_navigationBarHeightInPx = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(n_idNavigationBarHeight);
    }
    else
    {
        n_navigationBarHeightInPx = 0;
    }
    return n_navigationBarHeightInPx;
}

private int returnActionBarHeightInPx()
{
TypedValue typedValue            = null;
int        n_actionBarHeightInPx = -1;

    typedValue = new TypedValue();

    if(getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, typedValue, true))
    {
        n_actionBarHeightInPx =
                TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
                            typedValue.data,
                            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    return n_actionBarHeightInPx;
}

private int returnDisplayHeightInPx()
{
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics      = null;
int            n_displayHeightInPx = -1;

    displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    n_displayHeightInPx = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    return n_displayHeightInPx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to know it in "//here". You do not use that variable there. Your code does not explain, why it is not possible, to define the variable on scroll time.